# @ControllerAdvice does not allow Swagger UI to be displayed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui

I just add a GlobalExceptionHandler with @ControllerAdvice and when i try to access Swagger UI at `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#/` a get a message in the UI: `"Failed to load API definition"`and an exception in console.

Before adding the `GlobalExceptionHandler` implementation shown below, i could access Swagger UI with no problem.

Here is my `GlobalExceptionHandler.java` :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> resourceNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse();
        response.setErrorCode("NOT_FOUND");
        response.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        response.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

My `ExceptionResponse.java`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ExceptionResponse {
    private String errorMessage;
    private String errorCode;
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
}
```

My `ExceptionResponse.java`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter

@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

My `OpenApiConfig.java` (in case is needed) where i create Swagger:

```
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "bearerAuth",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        scheme = "bearer"
)
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean(name = "tutofastOpenApi")
    public OpenAPI tutofastOpenApi() {
        // Available at
        // http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components())
                .info(new Info().title("TutoFast Application API Documentation").description(
                        "TutoFast API implemented with Spring Boot RESTful service and documented using springdoc-openapi and OpenAPI 3."));
    }
}
```

My `WebSecurityConfig.java` in case is needed:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //Ignore Swagger UI
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()//TODO :MODIFICAR !!!!!!!
                .antMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/courses/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/plans/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/subscriptions/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/sessions/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

And this is the exception in got in console when i try to access Swagger UI:

```
2020-10-21 19:00:59.274  INFO 11216 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.t.TutofastBackendApplication         : Started TutofastBackendApplication in 33.173 seconds (JVM running for 46.787)
2020-10-21 19:01:17.050  INFO 11216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-21 19:01:17.050  INFO 11216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-21 19:01:17.109  INFO 11216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 59 ms
2020-10-21 19:01:22.982  INFO 11216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource  : Init duration for springdoc-openapi is: 3801 ms
2020-10-21 19:01:23.098 ERROR 11216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?) (through reference chain: io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI["paths"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Paths["/api/auth/signin"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem["post"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation["responses"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponses["null"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:288) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1337) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1231) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.FailingSerializer.serialize(FailingSerializer.java:35) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeOptionalFields(MapSerializer.java:785) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:677) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:637) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(SerializerProvider.java:1119) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ApiResponsesSerializer.serialize(ApiResponsesSerializer.java:35) ~[swagger-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ApiResponsesSerializer.serialize(ApiResponsesSerializer.java:11) ~[swagger-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeOptionalFields(MapSerializer.java:786) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:677) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:637) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(SerializerProvider.java:1119) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.PathsSerializer.serialize(PathsSerializer.java:35) ~[swagger-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.PathsSerializer.serialize(PathsSerializer.java:11) ~[swagger-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4407) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3661) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.openapiJson(OpenApiResource.java:110) ~[springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core-1.3.7.jar:1.3.7]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at com.evertix.tutofastbackend.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-10-21 19:01:23.156 ERROR 11216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.e.t.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt     : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource
2020-10-21 19:01:23.178 ERROR 11216 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use basePackages @RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.datahome.mc.controller")
```

Comment: Hi Malin. Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your contribution. But please add an explanation to all your answers even if it is only a brief one. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by conflict between ControllerAdvice and swagger.

Without ControllerAdvice, swagger will reflect the controller class and analyse the api define, it works fine. But after use ControllerAdvice, the swagger response will alse be transform by ControllerAdvice, then swagger web page can't recognize the response struct.

So the solution is specify the package which will use ControllerAdvice, so swagger controller will not be transformed.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"foo.bar.controller"})
public class CommonResponseAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice {
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating dependency to latest version make it work

Old one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

New one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

"To generate documentation automatically, make sure all the methods declare the HTTP Code responses using the annotation: @ResponseStatus"
https://springdoc.org/#error-handling-for-rest-using-controlleradvice

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)