How to use both @RestControllerAdvice and Swagger UI in Spring boot
I have a very simple Spring boot project contains Swagger UI:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

After I setting a class has @RestControllerAdvice, trying to view swagger UI throw an exception:

And the log is
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.web.method.ControllerAdviceBean.<init>(java.lang.Object)'

The tree:
└───com
    └───cuong02n
        └───test
            │   App.java
            │
            ├───controller
            │       CourseController.java
            │       StudentController.java
            │
            └───exception
                    CustomExceptionHandler.java <-- The @RestControllerAdvice here
                    StudentException.java

After reading and trying some solutions by adding basePackage, I still can't access Swagger UI.
Update
The pom.xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cuong02n</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-controller-advice-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-controller-advice-swagger</name>
    <description>test-controller-advice-swagger</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473435/controlleradvice-does-not-allow-swagger-ui-to-be-displayed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70943125/spring-boot-openapi-restcontrolleradvice-not-limited-to-methods-throwing-the

@jcompetence, I have already found that question, but I tried add basePackage, it not work. Can you help me a completed basePackage?

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  generally those come from mixing incompatible versions.  Add your full pom.xml to the question.

@M.Deinum That error only occur by adding @RestControllerAdvice. I also updated the pom.xml in question.

I would suggest to use the most recent version of springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui (version 2.7.0 I think), as the version in use is from beginning of this years which is way before Spring Boot 3.4 and Spring 6.2 so I doubt it is compatible (and could pull in conflicting dependencies).

@M.Deinum. Finally I downgrade spring parent from 3.4.0 to 3.3.5 and it works.

As mentioned, incompatible versions.

According to @M.Deinum, this caught by incompatible, I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 3.4.0 and springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui 2.5.0. They are conflicted.
My solution is downgrade spring to 3.3.5 and it works well.

With spring-boot-starter-parent 3.4.0 and springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui 2.6.0, one solution is to disable generic responses generated by springdoc using
the @ControllerAdvice.
You can do this by setting the following property:
springdoc.override-with-generic-response=false

Here is the link to the documentation about this property:
springdoc documentation
Where it states:

springdoc.override-with-generic-response | true | Boolean. When true, automatically adds @ControllerAdvice responses to all the generated responses.


I am encountering the same issue as you. I am using the following versions in my pom.xml:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I was facing the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError,
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.web.method.ControllerAdviceBean.<init>(java.lang.Object)'

but I was able to resolve it by using @Hidden from SpringDoc. Specifically, you need to add @Hidden on your @RestControllerAdvice or @ControllerAdvice classes  (see the documentation here: SpringDoc - How to hide an operation or controller).
@Slf4j
@Hidden
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
...
}

This solution provides a temporary fix while using the versions of Spring Boot and SpringDoc that I want, without causing any errors.

Another helpful response.

added below annotation for my GlobalExceptionHandler  class and then run the mvn command : mvn clean install and run the application, later I am able to view http://localhost:----/swagger-ui/index.html#/
@Hidden
@ControllerAdvice
